# How does iptables --hitcount collect its values?

Tags: iptables

I'm looking at SSH brute force prevention with iptables recent module.

I would like to know how does the --hitcount collect the value that it will use? Is it bytes, packets, no. of conntracked items or something else?

Comment: The counter gets updated whenever the rule to do so is triggered. That depends on how and where you configure it, so include your iptables rule set for an actual answer please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--rcheck --hitcount` checks the value of an internal counter which is incremented by one for each hit on a `-m recent --set` (or `--update`) rule of the same `--name`.  Rules are evaluated in the context of packets, so the number of packets is the tracked quantity.  This from the `man` page for `iptables` on my CentOS 6 system:

> ```
>    --hitcount hits
> ```
>
> [...] When used, this will narrow the match to only happen when the address
>   is in the list and packets had been received greater than or equal to
>   the given value.

Comment: It's not just the same `--name`, it's also the _same thing_ being counted (either `--rsource` or `--rdest`). In most cases, the source (client) IP address.

Answer (score 0):

The list of items are saved in a file under `/proc/net/xt_recent/...`. If you do not use the `--name my-name` option, then the name is set to `DEFAULT`.

To see the recent lists, just use `ls`:

```
ls /proc/net/xt_recent
```

To see the contents of one of those files, you can simply use `less`:

```
less -S /proc/net/xt_recent/DEFAULT
```

The fields are named, so it should be easy to understand what they represent. The date is a large number about 4x the standard Unix date (I've not yet figured out how they generate that number).

Now, if you want to know how many times it was hit, you want to count the number of timestamps starting from column 8. I do that with the following `awk` command:

```
awk '{out="";for(i=1;i<=7;i++){out=out" "$i};print out,"hitcount:",NF-7}' /proc/net/xt_recent/DEFAULT
```

It prints the first 7 columns as is, then it shows the total number of columns minus 7 which represents the hitcount.

As a side note, the maximum number of hits is 255. I have not seen that number documented, but if you try to use `--hitcount 500`, it won't work.